# Delete from table using column of other table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have created a procedure in which I create a temporary table to store the value of a column and then I want to use those column values to delete the data in other tables.
How do I do this in while loop or simply can I use join to delete rows from AppCoverLetter, AppError which way is better?

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `gdpr_delete`(_email_ varchar(128))
BEGIN
DECLARE NumberRecords int;
DECLARE RowCount int ;
-- Create a temporary table, note the IDENTITY
-- column that will be used to loop through
-- the rows of this table
CREATE TABLE GdprDeleteData (AppId INT NOT null);

-- Insert the resultset we want to loop through
-- into the temporary table

INSERT INTO  GdprDeleteData (AppId) SELECT AppId FROM ApplyData.AppFormData where lower(Email) = lower(_email_);
-- Get the number of records in the temporary table
SET NumberRecords = ROW_COUNT();
SET RowCount = 1;
select NumberRecords, RowCount;
-- loop through all records in the temporary table
-- using the WHILE loop construct
start transaction;
    DELETE AppCoverLetter  FROM AppCoverLetter inner JOIN GdprDeleteData ON AppCoverLetter.AppID = GdprDeleteData.AppId;
    DELETE AppError        FROM AppError inner JOIN GdprDeleteData ON AppError.AppID = GdprDeleteData.AppId;
    DELETE AppFormData     FROM AppFormData inner JOIN GdprDeleteData ON AppFormData.AppID = GdprDeleteData.AppId;
    DELETE AppJobData      FROM AppJobData inner JOIN GdprDeleteData ON AppJobData.AppID = GdprDeleteData.AppId;
    DELETE AppTrackingData FROM AppTrackingData inner JOIN GdprDeleteData ON AppTrackingData.AppID = GdprDeleteData.AppId;
    DELETE FlowLog         FROM FlowLog inner JOIN GdprDeleteData ON FlowLog.AppID = GdprDeleteData.AppId;
    DELETE App             FROM App inner JOIN GdprDeleteData ON App.AppID = GdprDeleteData.AppId;
    DELETE AppCoverLetter  FROM AppCoverLetter inner JOIN GdprDeleteData ON AppCoverLetter.AppID = GdprDeleteData.AppId;
    DELETE AppResume       FROM AppResume inner JOIN GdprDeleteData ON AppResume.AppID = GdprDeleteData.AppId;

  commit;
-- drop the temporary table

drop table  GdprDeleteData;
END
```

Comment: What's you question ?  .. you have an error ?? show the error message .. wrong result update you question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I want to know which way is better the current one delete using a join or should I do while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the temporary table and loop
in mysql you can  delete form the two table in single query  and use a sunquery for the temporary data

```
   DELETE t1, t2
   FROM AppCoverLetter t1
   INNER JOIN (
     SELECT AppId 
     FROM ApplyData.AppFormData 
     where lower(Email) = lower(_email_)
   ) t3 ON t1.AppID = t3.AppId
   INNER JOIN AppError t2 ON t2.AppID = t3.AppId;
```

or if you ahve more table

```
   DELETE t1, t2, tx
   FROM AppCoverLetter t1
   INNER JOIN (
     SELECT AppId 
     FROM ApplyData.AppFormData 
     where lower(Email) = lower(_email_)
   ) t3 ON t1.AppID = t3.AppId
   INNER JOIN AppError t2 ON t2.AppID = t3.AppId
   INNER JOIN table3 tx ON tx.AppID = t3.AppId;
```

Comment: what if i have more than 2 tables please check edit in question @scaisEdge

Comment: answer updated ..  you just need the table refernce in delete clause and the related  join

Comment: it is giving syntax error for more than one table @scaisEdge

Comment: removed the wrong ; at the end of first join answer  updated ..

Comment: it does not delete data if 1 out of these 3 tables don't have match condition / don't have data @scaisEdge

Comment: if you have not matching values with some table  query don't return rows ..so the delete in not performed ..  you must build proper delete only with matching rows tables. if if you have optional table or  relation use specific single delete with join  ..

Comment: I dont know in advance if i have matching rows or not , but delete should be performed for those tables which have matching rows, here if either table doesn't have matching rows delete is not performed.

Comment: then instead of one snigle super delete join yiu should build separated  delete each one with a single join  .. this however better then a loop on each appId result  ..

Comment: can you answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347102/deleting-multiple-tables-using-join-not-deleting-for-all-tables