# Deleting multiple tables using join not deleting for all tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am deleting from multiple tables using joins, but the problem with this query is if one table doesn't contain matching values/ is empty the delete is not performed for the tables which have matching values and data.
How can I resolve this?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `gdpr_delete`(_email_ varchar(128))
BEGIN
   DELETE AppCoverLetter, AppError, AppFormData, AppJobData, AppTrackingData, FlowLog, App,AppResume
   FROM AppCoverLetter t1
   INNER JOIN (
     SELECT AppId 
     FROM ApplyData.AppFormData 
     where lower(Email) = lower(_email_)
   ) t3 ON t1.AppID = t3.AppId
   INNER JOIN AppError        ON AppError.AppID = t3.AppId
   INNER JOIN AppCoverLetter  ON AppCoverLetter.AppID = t3.AppId
   INNER JOIN AppFormData     ON AppFormData.AppID = t3.AppId
   INNER JOIN AppJobData      ON AppJobData.AppID = t3.AppId
   INNER JOIN AppTrackingData ON AppTrackingData.AppID = t3.AppId
   INNER JOIN FlowLog         ON FlowLog.AppID = t3.AppId
   INNER JOIN App             ON App.AppID = t3.AppId
   INNER JOIN AppResume       ON AppResume.AppID = t3.AppId;
END
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete from table using column of other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66346123/delete-from-table-using-column-of-other-table)

Comment: no, its a different use case,

Answer (score 0):

if you heve not alway matching rows you can use separated  delete with single join for avoid loop

```
   DELETE  tx
   FROM table3 tx
   INNER JOIN (
     SELECT AppId 
     FROM ApplyData.AppFormData 
     where lower(Email) = lower(_email_)
   ) t3 ON tx.AppID = t3.AppId
```

But could be you have some tables with a solid persistent relation and then for these table you can use a single query for multiple delete and leave the single join delete only to the optional relation